# Bootstrap Container within a Parent-Div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys and thanks for reading my post,

i just wanted to know how to use the bootstrap grid system WITHIN an already existing "Container"-Class wich has full width but percentage margins on the Left and Right to center the Content.

My problem is that i have a container class (not called container) with margin-left/right with a percentage so it will always have the same margin at all resolutions. If i place the "container"-class of Bootstrap, it will take the margin-left and start there but it leaks out on the right side.
I thought it would be a collapsing issue, but it happens even if my parent got a border/padding etc.

And yes, i could rebuild it completely out of bootstrap, but i just don't want to change that much, only if i have no other possibilities.

thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: can you show a demo on fiddle.?

Comment: I do it all the time. I totally remove BS3 container and use my own, just one, with a percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion:

just added min-width: 100% to my container and it works properly.

Thanks anyways